# Image not uploading from Axios into file system nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to generate a QR for our products by calling a URL to generate the QR image and store that image into our server. What is weird about this is that if I run the function from the file itself, it works. But if I run this using a GET request from client, it does not work.

QRGenerator Code.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const Path = require('path');

let requestQRGenerate = async (Tag)=>{
console.log(Tag);



    var url = `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=localhost:4200/pages/inventory/:${Tag}`


    const imagePath = `${Tag.split(':').join('.')}`;
    console.log(imagePath); 
    // let path = Path.resolve(__dirname, '../images',imagePath+'.jpg');
    let path = Path.resolve(__dirname, '../images');
    path = path + '/' + imagePath+'.jpg';
    //console.log(path+'/'+imagePath);


    const response = await axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        responseType: 'stream'
    })


    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));

return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    response.data.on('end', () =>{
        resolve('QR Generated for reel successfully')
    })
    response.data.on('error', (err)=>{
        reject(err);
    }) 
})

}

requestQRGenerate('06C-01003G-21:3975')


module.exports.requestQRGenerate = requestQRGenerate;
```

You can tell I was trying many things trying to format the string to save the file as. I basically need the file to save as the Tag variable, and since I can't have ":" in a file name, I replace it with "." and then .jpg.

inventoryController.js

```
exports.generateQRCode = 
async (req,res,next)=>{
try {
    let Tag = req.body.tag


    let TagRes = await requestQRGen.requestQRGenerate(Tag);

    res.status(200).send(TagRes)
} catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({
        Status: "Error",
        Content: e 
    })
}
```

This is the error I get when I try executing the function from a GET request.

```
events.js:174
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ' 
C:\Domains\App\images\06C-01003G-21.3975
.jpg'
Emitted 'error' event at:
at WriteStream.onerror (_stream_readable.js:713:12)
at WriteStream.emit (events.js:189:13)
at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:272:12)
at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
```

I do not understand why it's not working through a GET request but works when I run the file itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh and also, if I have const imagePath = `${Tag.split(':')[0] instead of .join("."), it works even when called from GET request...but the problem is, I need the last set of 4 digits at the end of that string to make each image file unique.

Comment: I figured out the problem.